# 4 column DIVs at 24% width won't extend all the way across my 100% screen width div

Tags: css, html, padding, reset

Can someone please tell me why 'Security Professionals' on the bottom right won't extend all the way to the right side of the screen? I'm using Eric Meyer's reset. I don't know why there's that padding there.

http://hemakessites.com/mayukh/22/

Edit: You guys are seeing the huge block of space on the bottom right, right? It's not a 3% sliver. I'll try wrapping them in a div, because right now if I set all of them to 25% one of them falls to the next line.

Aside: Oh my god. I just finished a sentence with a semicolon; I've been programming too much;

Update: There's already a div container that stretches 100%. That's what the gray area is. No... this is an evil far worse than we ever imagined. Maybe it's got something to do with the 'Difference' div being fixed?

Comment: One good answer and 2 patch :) Sometimes people answer too fast!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `box-sizing` property for your solution i hope this will work for you

please update your **css** with mine **css**

```
.slagline {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    border-color: #FFFFFF #666666 #CCCCCC #CCCCCC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Actually the main thing is you have defined `border-width:1px;` so its increasing the width of all of your four columns so by `box-sizing` property you can get your desired results

see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jxyF3/4/) if you will remove the `box-sizing` u will know the difference...

Comment: @TylerLangan hey chill i just tried to solve your issue :-) what i have learned here i shared with you so don't give me so much designations :-) i m nothing..... pleasure to help you.....

Answer (score 1):

Because you set `float: left` on them, and as you said you gave them a width of 24%. The padding you experience are the leftover 4%. Make the last one float: right or apply margins/paddings to all boxes.

If you're setting 24% because of border problems, I'd suggest to create e.g a div that wraps your content in your floated blocks. So you can set the width of your current blocks to 25% and they expand accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="slg4">
```

Needs to be set to float:right;

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<div style="width:27%;" class="slagline" id="slg4">
```